# Не удается построить маршрут в 2GIS из более, чем 2 точек на iOS путем открытия приложения через deeplink

Tags: ios, 2gis-api, deeplink

Мне необходимо построить маршрут в 2Gis картах, который имеет текущее местоположение в качестве начальной точки и три - четыре точки на маршруте. Я формирую такой uri:

```
dgis://2gis.ru/directions/points/%7C49.102084,55.768309%7C49.218596,55.712502%7C49.219206,55.683371%7C49.130255,55.674296?m=<<координаты текущего местоположения>>/
```

При запуске этой ссылки на ОС Android маршрут строится корректно:

[image: Пример построенного маршрута в Android]

Однако при запуске на iOS строится путь только до точки 49.102084,55.768309 (первая в списке переданных) от текущего местоположения:
[image: Пример построенного маршрута в iOS]

Такой формат маршрута я взял в web-версии, однако он нигде не упоминается в официальной документации. А еще в официальной документации нет ни единого упоминания (или я не нашел?) о том, как строить маршруты с несколькими промежуточными точками.

Помогите пожалуйста найти корректное решение по формированию deeplink'ов в 2GIS для построения маршрутов с несколькими промежуточными точками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, такая диплинка на iOS ещё не поддерживается. Почему я так думаю:

1. На iOS ещё даже нельзя построить маршрут с промежуточными точками, выбирая их из UI поиска на экране построения маршрута (как на андроиде). Пару лет назад на iOS сделали промежуточные точки в режиме ведения нового навигатора, а потом и при выборе логтапом с карты на экране построения. Остался последний, самый сложный шаг - добавить выбор точек на сам экран построения. Он ещё не сделан и очевидно бы был приоритетнее, чем диплинка.
2. На Андроиде фичи в мобильный 2гис поставляются (и исторически поставлялись) быстрее. Просто разработчиков тупо больше, как и аудитории.
3. Этот экран ещё в старом дизайне, когда как последние пару лет приложение методично редизайнится. Сначала навигатор, потом дашборд, теперь экран поиска и карточки - скорее всего этот экран если не прямо следующий, то скоро будет полностью переделан. Его переделка очевидно приоритетнее диплинки, либо же диплинка появится вместе с редизайном.